# Not able to upload multiple files with IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have scenario where the user selects 4 images to upload and I need to bind this four files to my model and save into the folder. but the problem I am facing is my model when reaches to action method it will be null.

My View :

```
@using(@Html.BeginForm("fileUpload","Home",FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
<div>
    <h1>Auto Upload</h1>
</div>
<div>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyFile, new { id = "file1" , Type = "file" })</div>
<div>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyFile, new { id = "file2" , Type = "file" })</div>
<div>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyFile, new { id = "file3" , Type = "file" })</div>
<div>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyFile, new { id = "file4" , Type = "file" })</div>
<input type ="submit" name ="submit" />
}
```

My Model :

```
public class MyModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> MyFile { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller : When I click on submit in my controller's fileUpload method I get files = null.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public void fileUpload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
        {
            string s = "upload";
        }
```

I am very new to file upload things compared to my usual work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're displaying the same textbox four times with the same name but a different id, the model binder has no idea you're trying to post a collection named `files`. Also don't use the `TextBoxFor` helper here, nothing wrong with using plain old HTML elements in this situation.

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("fileUpload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <label for="file1">File :</label>
    <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />

    <label for="file2">File :</label>
    <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" />

    <label for="file3">File :</label>
    <input type="file" name="files" id="file3" />

    <label for="file4">File :</label>
    <input type="file" name="files" id="file4" />

    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
}
```

Your controller method signature then stays intact, but you'll see the `files` collection is properly filled.

```
[HttpPost]
public void fileUpload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        // Validate size (in bytes), set your limit accordingly
        if (file.ContentLength > 0  && file.ContentLength <= 2097152)
        {
            // Do something with your files
        }
    }
}
```

The important thing to keep in mind is that model binding works based on the `name` attribute given to form elements. The way you had it, inputs were rendered something like `<input name="MyFile">` so when posted back to the server, there's nothing indicating that it should bind to a collection called `files`.

Comment: Thanks Dom your solution is working fine. but my model has few more properties which I have not added to the model because it was not necessary. Will that work fine even if I use the same code

Comment: Yes, just update your controller action signature to `public void fileUpload(MyModel model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)` and proceed as you usually would with your model.

Comment: Thank You very much dom. Can you please let me know how can i control file size to min and max before hitting to controllers action method using JQuery?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how to do it server side. But as far as how to do it using jQuery goes, I can't help you as that's not something I'm familiar with. A quick search led me to [this](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/checking-file-size-before-uploading-it) which might point you in the right direction.